# Django Crispy Forms Inline Fields in Horizontal Form

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

I want to be able to do the ff:

[image]

I was following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021746/get-two-fields-inline-in-django-crispy-forms-but-not-others-horizontal). However, I can't fully implement how I want it. I have the following set-up:

```
self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-2'
self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-8 col-md-7'
self.helper.form_method = 'post'
self.fields['size_min'].label = False
self.fields['size_max'].label = False
```

I also have this layout:

```
Div(
    Div(HTML("<b>Class Size</b>"), css_class='col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-right', style='padding: 0; padding-top: 8px;'),
    Div(Field('size_min', placeholder='Min', css_class='text-center'), css_class='col-sm-6', style='margin-left: 16px;'),
    Div(HTML("<b>to</b>"), css_class='text-center', style='padding: 0; padding-top: 8px;'),
    Div(Field('size_max', placeholder='Max', css_class='text-center'), css_class='col-sm-6'),
    css_class="row col-sm-12"
),
```

But that only ends up looking like this:

[image]

Performing "Inspect Element" in Chrome, I observed this:

[image]

I think that `self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-8 col-md-7'` is still in play, causing the odd spaces despite setting `self.fields['size_max'].label = False`. Is there a way to override this? Simply setting `css_class` in the Divs/Fields does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?